# How to set the AutoSizeMode of columns in the ParentChanged handler without DataError exception with context: "Formatting, PreferredSize"?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is visible only sometimes. I saw that I the following events are triggered in this order:

1. `HandleCreated`;
2. `VisibleChanged`;
3. `ParentChanged`.

So I put the code that sets all the columns to fill the table in a `ParentChanged` handler. But I still get this DataError.

I could not find a similar question that helps me.

I have started handling the `DataError` by myself so I can see details of the error. What I've found is:

- Context: `Formatting, PreferredSize`.
- Column: ComboBox column that accepts new entries introduced into the menu on Enter.
- Message: "DataGridViewComboBoxCell is not valid".
- One message box for each row that has a non-empty string as value in this column. Note: the ComboBox column has a data source that is a List of something else than strings. I set the `DisplayMember` and the `ValueMember`, and also the `ValueType` to `typeof(string)` (If I set it to `ListControlItem` I get `DataError`-s about context `Display` and I do not know if I should continue on this track).

My program is pretty big so I do not know what part of the code to show. Here is the stack trace of the `OnDataError` call:

```
cs_timed_silver.ClockDataGridView.OnDataError(bool displayErrorDialogIfNoHandler = true, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs}) Line 2016
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\SplitterPanels\ClockDataGridView.cs(2016)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDataErrorInternal(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell.GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex = 0, ref System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle}, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter = null, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context = Formatting | PreferredSize)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell.GetPreferredSize(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = {System.Drawing.Graphics}, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex, System.Drawing.Size constraintSize)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredWidth(int rowIndex, int height)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.GetPreferredWidth(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode autoSizeColumnMode, bool fixedHeight = true)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AutoResizeColumnInternal(int columnIndex = 6, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnCriteriaInternal autoSizeColumnCriteriaInternal, bool fixedHeight)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnAutoSizeColumnModeChanged(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnModeEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnModeEventArgs})
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnAutoSizeColumnModeChanged(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode previousInheritedMode)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode.set(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode value)
cs_timed_silver.ClockDataGridView.Cms_ResizeColumnsToFill(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 200
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\SplitterPanels\ClockDataGridView.cs(200)
cs_timed_silver.ClockDataGridView.Item_CheckedChanged(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 1003
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\SplitterPanels\ClockDataGridView.cs(1003)
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnCheckedChanged(System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState.set(System.Windows.Forms.CheckState value)
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.Checked.set(bool value)
cs_timed_silver.MainForm.ApplySetting(cs_timed_silver.SettingData sd = {cs_timed_silver.SettingData}) Line 650
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Views\MainForm.cs(650)
cs_timed_silver.MainForm.Settings_SettingValueChange(object sender = {cs_timed_silver.SettingData}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 660
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Views\MainForm.cs(660)
cs_timed_silver.SettingDataCollection.Ds_Changed(object sender = {cs_timed_silver.SettingData}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 204
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\SettingDataCollection.cs(204)
cs_timed_silver.SettingData.Value.set(object value = true) Line 61
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\SettingData.cs(61)
cs_timed_silver.SettingDataCollection.SetValue(string v = "AutoresizeTableColumns", object value = true) Line 320
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\SettingDataCollection.cs(320)
cs_timed_silver.SettingDataCollection.LoadBoolAttribute(System.Xml.XmlDocument d = {System.Xml.DebuggerDisplayXmlNodeProxy}, string s = "AutoresizeTableColumns") Line 344
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\SettingDataCollection.cs(344)
cs_timed_silver.SettingDataCollection.ImportFromAttributes(System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = {System.Xml.DebuggerDisplayXmlNodeProxy}) Line 450
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\SettingDataCollection.cs(450)
cs_timed_silver.DataFile.LoadFromString(string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>...") Line 511
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\DataFile.cs(511)
cs_timed_silver.DataFile.LoadFromFile(string filePath = "C:\\...\\test.xml") Line 753
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Models\DataFile.cs(753)
cs_timed_silver.MainForm.LoadLastOpenFile() Line 2226
    at E:\Lucru\cs-timed-silver\cs-timeout\Views\MainForm.cs(2226)
cs_timed_silver.MainForm.MainForm_Load(object sender = {cs_timed_silver.MainForm}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 2177
```

A method is this:

```
internal void Cms_ResizeColumnsToFill(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyFillColumnsItem.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }
        Columns[(int)TimerColumns.Tag].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = Columns[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
        }
    }

    MyDataFile.SetValue("AutoresizeTableColumns", MyFillColumnsItem.Checked);
}
```

I expected that there was no `DataError` event triggered. The actual result is that there is a `DataError` event triggered. The program does not work well even if I handle the DataError event without showing anything: when typing a new value in the ComboBox it is created in the model and shown as selected in the ComboBox, but when I select an exiting value (including the one that has the corresponding value set to an empty string) the ComboBox shows just as if I did nothing, after closing its drop-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an older problem. The program has a user setting that makes the data grid view to have all columns in `Fill` mode, or all the columns taking as much width as they need (`AllCells`). When the user changed this setting, this called a setting application method that also changed the checkbox of that setting. This recursivity was blocking the data grid so much that one of the columns which was a `ComboBox` column never loaded its possible values (`Items`).

I had to comment this line from the code in the question:

```
MyDataFile.SetValue("AutoresizeTableColumns", MyFillColumnsItem.Checked);
```

and move most of the code related to this setting to MainForm's setting application method:

```
case "AutoresizeTableColumns":
    ClockDataGridView cdgv = MyClocksViewProvider.GetExistingOrNewClockDataGridView();
    if (!cdgv.FirstParentChange)
    {
        cdgv.MyFillColumnsItem.Checked =
            (bool)MyDataFile.GetValue("AutoresizeTableColumns");

        if (cdgv.MyFillColumnsItem.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
            {
                cdgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            }
            cdgv.Columns[(int)ClockDataGridView.TimerColumns.Tag].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn col = cdgv.Columns[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
            {
                cdgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cdgv.ParentChanged += Cdgv_ParentChanged;
    }
    break;
```

Finally:

```
internal void Cms_ResizeColumnsToFill(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDataFile.SetValue("AutoresizeTableColumns", MyFillColumnsItem.Checked);
}
```

and:

```
private void Cdgv_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClockDataGridView cdgv = MyClocksViewProvider.GetExistingOrNewClockDataGridView();

    if (cdgv.MyFillColumnsItem.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            cdgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }
        cdgv.Columns[(int)ClockDataGridView.TimerColumns.Tag].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = cdgv.Columns[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cdgv.Columns.Count; ++i)
        {
            cdgv.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
        }
    }

    cdgv.ParentChanged -= Cdgv_ParentChanged;
}
```